# Need help identifying Zemirot from audio (very simple to anyone with good hebrew)

Tags: shabbat, shabbat-songs

I'm currently on teshuva path and right now I'm trying to learn some zemirot for shabbat table.

Would anyone please help me identify the first one on this youtube video?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1VZWPCCZuU

It's from 0:00 to 1:45. My hebrew isn't very good and I have a hard time dealing with heavy ashkenaz accent.

The second one I'm sure it's Chai Hashem, I just need to find the first one.

And there's a third one at 5:48 which I also can't identify.

I tried searching at http://www.zemirotdatabase.org but no luck, I can't understand/spell most of the words properly.

May everyone have a blessed week.
Kol tuv!

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Jacob and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Thank you, this website is great, I'll have a read at those right now!

Comment: And if you are interested I also wrote [this](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) as a guide which might help understand the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first song is called אסדר לסעודתא (Asader leseudasa). The lyrics can be found [here](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8_%D7%9C%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%93%D7%AA%D7%90). Translation and transliteration [here](https://www.chabad.org/multimedia/media_cdo/aid/265781/jewish/Asader-Lsudoso.htm).

The second one you mentioned is from [Isaiah 58:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.58.13?with=all&lang=bi), and is said as part of Kiddush on Shabbos morning.

Comment: Thanks a ton Daniel, I can follow it now thanks to you. Having a look at the lyrics and the comments on the link you sent me makes me believe this set is meant to be sung before yom shabbat lunch. Best wishes

Comment: Theyre both from Kiddush

Comment: Chai Hashem is usually sung right after Asader L'seudasa, and a peak in Siddur Tefilas Kol Peh says it was composed by someone named "Chaim Yitzchak".

Comment: @Jacob Salzberg. May your Tshuva path be a smooth one. We are always more than happy to greet people like you, who aren't shy to ask, with open arms.

Comment: @Jacob Salzberg, By the way, many people don't sing these two songs. I believe it is mainly the Chassidim who sing Asader Leseudasa, whilst the second one, which Daniel already mentioned as being part of the Kiddush, is mainly said by Sfardim, and again possibly by some Chassidim. If you are struggling with them I would advise to skip them (for the moment).

Comment: @Imanonov, thank you for the clarification, that's very good information!! Currently I follow no particular minhag/hashkafa, I don't have enough knowledge or experience to "pick" any for myself. I don't come from a religious background so I'm trying to learn as much as I can, without "attaching" myself to any custom in particular. I was kindly invited to a haredi shabbat recently and I felt a bit "lost" with all the singing.. so at least I'll try to get (somewhat) familiarized with some of the zemirot. Thank you again for the kind words and information.